# What does the expression "goes the message" mean?

Tags: meaning, collocation

What does the expression "goes the message" mean?

I've just come across this expression and don't know how to explain /  understand it.

An example:

> - Another way showoffs try to show how smart they are is to drop a Very Smart Name: *If this brain is my friend*, goes the message, *I must be a brain too*.

Comment: It seems to mean something like 'so the message says' - the 'message' being that if I'm friends with a clever person I must be clever too.

Comment: I think it's probably more common in *British* English to use ***to go*** to mean ***to say***. But in the exact cited example, ***is the message*** would be perfectly good paraphrasing.

Comment: Or in olden days, **_runs the message_**. 'Go/run' (the latter used only with non-volitional 'sources' of communication, the former sometimes in the UK with speakers) here are non-central quotative verbs. // 'Collocations' are expressions used far more often than one would expect from a model based on random grammatical and  logical choices. 'Expressions' is a more general term  (though this is probably nothing more than a string, like 'John said').

Comment: 'Goes the **saying**', maybe, instead of 'goes the *message*'?

Comment: @Tim - maybe “goes the idea” .   ‘*If this brain is my friend, then I must be a brain too.’ Or so goes the idea.*

Comment: There's an implicit _so_ in all of these usages. They're interpolated, like _, said Harry,_ with comma intonations on both sides. The verb can be any verb that can refer to speaking - _go, say, run, ..._ and its subject (which can be postposed because _so_ allows inversion) can be any noun that can refer to some speaking - _story, message, ..._ It's used to avoid responsibility for repeating it, since you can blame it on an old story.